# Vlookup for double values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

How can i create a vlookup or VBA code such that the Vlookup function doesnt always take the first but after the first has been taken also a second value etc.
I think it becomes clearer with a screenshot [image]

Some further explanation:
Column A is an identifier (in the real sample the cusip (an Identification number) of a company)
Column B represents a Dealnumber.
But not for every deal cusips are availble (explains empty spaces), and a company can occur in several deals(-> values in column A are not mutually exclusive)

Since the values in column A are not mutually exclusive, i have to "map" the values of column B, which are mutually exclusive, to the occurance in column D

Comment: You are changing criterion when you move in your list, which isn't something general formulas can do.  E.g., lookup range is $A$1:$B$4, and if soemthing in row 1 is used your range switches to $A$2:$B$4... that would take VBA.  This is different from having a dynamic range, e.g. A1:B4 which will flow with the filldown of a formula in a column.

Comment: @Cyril yes i see your point... do you have any idea how to code smth like this? since i am unexperienced in vba -.-

Comment: What is the logic in your sequence, why is the second hit on A also 1 and so on, and only in row 7 you want to see the value of 4?

Comment: it is hard to explain.. basically you could see the numbers in b as a sequence of occurances, and the results in D as a count of observations. e.g. A occured 2 times on day 1, than B 2 times on day 2, C two times on day 3 and again A 3 times on day 4 and so on

Comment: @user11638654 with that understanding, is the goal to populate columns A & B manually based on the info in columns C & D, then populate C & D based on the manual entries?

Comment: i am not sure if i understood you correctly, but the goal is to populate column D with the "Date" of the respective observation for every occurance on that Date, so if a occurs on day 6 for the second time, than the second block of observations of A in column d should have 6 as match and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this, but it requires a title row on the data column:

```
=IF(D1=D2,E1,INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$1:$B$6)/($A$1:$A$6=D2),COUNTIFS($D$1:D1,D2,$D$2:D2,"<>"&D2)+1)))
```

It does not matter what the value in D1 is but the formula must be placed in the second row as it uses the first row as a check for changes.

[image]

---

Since this is an array type formula the references should limit themselves to the data set and not use full column references,  But we can use INDEx(MATCH()) to do that automatically:

```
=IF(D1=D2,E1,INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH("zzz",A:A)))/($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))=D2),COUNTIFS($D$1:D1,D2,$D$2:D2,"<>"&D2)+1)))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for this proposal! but unfortunately it works only partially, because on my orginal data i often get #num errors and sometimes it doesnt take the right occurance

Comment: the #num comes from the occurance of gaps in the data

Comment: @user11638654 If you fix the references it works regardless of the gaps.  For instance in your new example: `=IF(D1=D2,E1,INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($B$1:$B$10)/($A$1:$A$10=D2),COUNTIFS($D$1:D1,D2,$D$2:D2,"<>"&D2)+1)))`  Notice that the `$B$1:$B$6` and `$A$1:A$6` Changed to `$B$1:$B$10` and `$A$1:$A$10` respectively.

Comment: so if i understood you correctly, i have to count the number of gaps and add them to the arrays?

Comment: No, you need the two references to include the whole table.

Comment: @user11638654 this is an array type formula and as such the references should be limited to only the dataset.

Comment: @user11638654 see edit for a dynamic formula that will grow(or shrink) to the data set provided without the need for intervention.

Comment: Worsk perfctly! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding how your Columns A & B are being populated (by looking at occurrences in C & D), why not just use the C&D data?

You could find the number of tasks such that (I have this in D2):

```
=IFERROR(IF(C2=C1,D1,D1+1),1)
```

This will give the occurrences without using the Vlookup or Index/Match, adding 1 where the task changes (the iferror is used to give the first "1", since you can't add "occurrence" + 1).

[image]

Comment: because i have gaps in a, whereas b goes continously. i didnt think it was relevant, will post an update

Comment: @user11638654 I thnk i'm following you.  if you could ensure you explain in your update to the post how/why A & B are populated, it may help.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your answer by now.  Here's a nice (additional) solution.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$13, SMALL(IF(D$2=$A$3:$A$13, ROW($B$3:$B$13)-2,""), ROW()-2)),"")
```

or

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$13,SMALL(IF(D$2=$A$3:$A$13,ROW($A$3:$A$13)- MIN(ROW($A$3:$A$13))+1,""), ROW()-2)),"")
```

See this link:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/02/22/vlookup-multiple-values-excel/

To get VBA code, enter the function and get it working, then turn on the Macro Recorder, click on the primary cell (first cell), hit F2, hit Enter to commit the change, and double click the black cross to fill down.  Now, you should have all your VBA, and of course you can modify your code to do whatever you want.